# Strong Parameters create with belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I have a `Course` model which belongs_to a `Grade`. I'm trying to `create` a Course in my seeds.rb file by doing:

```
Course.create(
  ActionController::Parameters.new(
    grade: Grade.all.sample
  ).permit(:grade_id)
)
```

This creates a new `Course` object but `grade_id` is nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Agreed that nothing here needs to be sanitized (over simplified example) but why isn't this working?

Comment: Because you are setting `:grade`, not `:grade_id`. Permit `:grade` instead, or pass `:grade_id` into strong parameters with `Grade.all.sample.id`

Comment: I've tried using both `grade` and `grade_id` in `permit` and both gives me `nil`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strong parameters does two things: one is the white listing of parameters side of things (so the keys in the hash must match the arguments passed to permit, even if setting `grade` ends up setting `grade_id`.

The second thing it does is restrict the types of parameters that are passed - a lot of the recent security problems have occurred when an attacker is able to set a parameter to a carefully constructed hash/array/etc when you were only expecting a string or a number.

As a result anything that isn't a scalar value is stripped out, with arrays/hashes only allowed if you've indicated that you're expecting an array/hash. In particular your activerecord objects will be stripped out.

You could switch to setting `grade_id` instead it just not use strong parameters here - there's no untrusted user input in this case.

Answer (score 2):

@Frederick Cheung beat me to the cause. I will supplement his answer by providing some output from the Rails console to support this.

It does not allow record instances

```
[11] pry(main)> u = User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "user_users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, ...>
[12] pry(main)> x = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: u)
=> {"user"=>
  #<User id: 1, ...>}
[13] pry(main)> x.permit(:user)
Unpermitted parameters: user
=> {}
```

But if we switch to the scalar integer value for the record id it works fine.

```
[14] pry(main)> x = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: u.id)
=> {"user"=>1}
[15] pry(main)> x.permit(:user)
=> {"user"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a Course instance to seed the database, then you don't need to create it from as ActionController::Parameters

You can simply pass the attributes to Course.create like this:

```
Course.create(grade: Grade.all.sample)
```

Since you will not be using ActionController::Parameters at all, then you don't need to worry about strong parameters or permit at all (in your seeds).